# Prevent Response from server to overwrite older responses

Tags: c#, websocket, websocket-sharp

Currently I have a working WebSocket-Sharp Client that allows user to send a request on button_click event. I also receive the response from the server in a richtextbox(either NTF or RSP).

```
    Private void InstantiateWebSocket()
{
client=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:80");
client.OnMessage+=new EventHandler<MessageEventArgs>(client_OnMessage);
client.ConnectAsync();
}
```

and OnMessage

```
private void client_OnMessage(object sender,MessageEventArgs e)
{
if(e.IsText)
{
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() richTextBox1.text=e.Data;}));
return;
}
}
```

The issue that I am currently facing is that whenever a response is received by the client, it overwrites the older response. I would like newer responses to be written below the older response

```
    older response..
    new line
    newer response
```

Comment: You need to append the content of the new message to the `Text` property, not just overwrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the existing richTextBox1 text:

```
richTextBox1.Text+=e.Data;
```

Note: If you want to use/process these responses later store them in some collection together with a timestamp.

add a private field i.e.

```
private ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>> _messages = new ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>>();
```

And then just do this inside your message received code:

```
_messages.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>(DateTime.Now, e.Data));
```

Comment: using the responses was something I was gonna ask after this as well!Thanks for answering ahead of time haha :D

Comment: :) nice to hear that